I'm having issues trying to create an alert message on the screen when a bounding box touches a "region of interest" with RSTP
I'm doing object detection using yolov8 and I am trying to create a feature where it displays a red box in the middle of the output screen. If any 2 bounding boxes touches the red box for 1.5 seconds, it will create a text message on the screen where the red box is at for 2.5 seconds thereafter it will disappear until another 2 bounding boxes touches the red box. The message will only appear if 2 concurrent bounding boxes are touching the red box.
The scenario is that my "region of interest" is a table. If any 2 bounding boxes (body) are touching the region of interest it will show the alert. As we only want 1 person at the table at a time.
This is my code:
import time
import collections
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

# Load the YOLOv8 model using the specified model path
model = YOLO(model_path)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://Object_Detection:camera_password@105.160.30.200:554/stream1')

# Define constants
ROI_WIDTH = 400  # Width of the ROI
ROI_HEIGHT = 400  # Height of the ROI
MIN_DETECTION_TIME = 1.0  # seconds for which the bounding box must be within the ROI
ALERT_DURATION = 2.0  # seconds for which the alert message will be displayed

# Initialize tracking dictionary
tracking_info = collections.defaultdict(list)

# Define the codec and create a VideoWriter object for saving the output video
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
output_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
output_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
output_fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
output_video = cv2.VideoWriter('alert1.mp4', codec, output_fps, (output_width, output_height))

# Calculate the center of the frame
frame_center_x = output_width // 2
frame_center_y = output_height // 2

# Calculate the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the ROI
ROI_TOP_LEFT = (frame_center_x - ROI_WIDTH // 2, frame_center_y - ROI_HEIGHT // 2)
ROI_BOTTOM_RIGHT = (frame_center_x + ROI_WIDTH // 2, frame_center_y + ROI_HEIGHT // 2)

# Initialize alert state
alert_active = False
alert_end_time = None

# Loop through the video frames
while cap.isOpened():
    # Read a frame from the video
    success, frame = cap.read()

    if success:
        # Run YOLOv8 inference on the frame
        results = model.track(frame, persist=True, classes=[1])  # 1 for body

        # Get the current timestamp
        current_time = time.time()

        # Count the number of bounding boxes touching the ROI
        boxes_in_roi = 0

        for result in results:
            for box in result.boxes:
                # Ensure the box contains the expected xyxy attributes
                if hasattr(box, 'xyxy') and len(box.xyxy) == 4:
                    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = box.xyxy

                    # Check if any part of the bounding box is within the ROI
                    if (x_min < ROI_BOTTOM_RIGHT[0] and x_max > ROI_TOP_LEFT[0] and
                        y_min < ROI_BOTTOM_RIGHT[1] and y_max > ROI_TOP_LEFT[1]):
                        # Add timestamp to tracking info
                        tracking_info[box.id].append(current_time)
                        boxes_in_roi += 1

        # Check if there is at least 1 bounding box in the ROI for the required duration
        if boxes_in_roi >= 1:
            for timestamps in tracking_info.values():
                timestamps = [t for t in timestamps if t > current_time - MIN_DETECTION_TIME]
                tracking_info[box.id] = timestamps  # Update the timestamps
                if len(timestamps) >= 2:
                    if not alert_active:
                        alert_active = True
                        alert_end_time = current_time + ALERT_DURATION
                        print(f"Alert triggered at {current_time}.")
                    break
        else:
            alert_active = False

        # Visualize the results on the frame
        annotated_frame = results[0].plot()

        # Draw the detection area (box-shaped region of interest)
        cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, ROI_TOP_LEFT, ROI_BOTTOM_RIGHT, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Display the alert message if the condition is met
        if alert_active:
            if current_time <= alert_end_time:
                text = "Alert Message"
                text_size = cv2.getTextSize(text, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)[0]
                text_x = ROI_TOP_LEFT[0] + (ROI_WIDTH - text_size[0]) // 2
                text_y = ROI_TOP_LEFT[1] + (ROI_HEIGHT + text_size[1]) // 2

                # Draw a background rectangle for better visibility
                cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (text_x - 10, text_y - text_size[1] - 10), 
                              (text_x + text_size[0] + 10, text_y + 10), (0, 0, 0), -1)
                
                # Draw the text
                cv2.putText(annotated_frame, text, (text_x, text_y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            else:
                alert_active = False
                print(f"Alert ended at {current_time}.")

        # Write the annotated frame to the output video
        output_video.write(annotated_frame)

        # Display the annotated frame
        cv2.imshow("YOLOv8 Inference", annotated_frame)

        # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        # Break the loop if the end of the video is reached
        break

# Release the video capture object and the output video object, and close the display window
cap.release()
output_video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

So far the red box and my bounding boxes are showing, I just cannot get the alert message to appear. I think the issue is that the code is not detecting when the bounding boxes are touching the red box which is my region of interest. I have tried to edit the code where it ends the loop and closes the video stream when the bounding box touches the red box, but the stream doesn't close. It just continue to display the red box in the middle of the screen and my bounding boxes around the screen.
